# Derive number of elements in columns greater than thresholds defined in a row from a different dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Given:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,5,8),
              c2 = c(7,3,5),
              c3 = c(5,8,1))
row.names(df1) <- c("r1", "r2", "r3")

df2 <- data.frame(c1 = c(2,5),
              c2 = c(1,3),
              c3 = c(6,8))
row.names(df2) <- c("r4", "r5")
```

How to find the number of element in df1 that is greater than the values in the respective columns in row r4 of df2 to get the answer c(2, 3, 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through rows of df2, and use *mapply* to compare each columns:

```
apply(df2, 1, function(i) colSums(mapply(">", df1, i)))
#    r4 r5
# c1  2  1
# c2  3  2
# c3  1  0
```